# Support SQL Server 2012 & 2016

Tags: sql-server

The product I am working on, needs to support an environment where either SQL Server 2012 or 2016 version can exist.

Hence for backward compatibility, it should be ensured that no features specific to 2016 should be used.

For example:

```
FOR JSON PATH
```

Is there a tool\compiler which makes sure that SQL scripts are valid according to SQL Server 2012 language specifications?

In case one uses a construct introduced in 2016, it should show an error.

Comment: That's already available with all versions of SQL Server. Just change the compatibility level of your SQL Server 2016 databases to 11. SSDT projects have a target version as well, so you can't use features that aren't supported by the target version

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any tool like that. The idea @PanagiotisKanavos has does not work reliably: If you in a script altered the compatibility level of a SQL Server 2016 database: `ALTER DATABASE mydb SET COMPATIBILITY LEVEL = 110` and then did a `SELECT * FROM sometable FOR JSON AUTO`, the `SELECT` would still work.

Comment: Compatibility level does NOT resolve any issue that can be, for example, try to use lead/lag functions on SQL Server 2012 but in database with compatibility level 90 (or 100), it will succeed. See the similar topic describing this:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5166/what-is-the-meaning-of-microsoft-compatibility-level